# fusion chart not supporting chinese characters

Tags: java, spring, charts

Fusion Chart not supporting chinese characters , I am using spring framework for this task, I am generating xml file dynamically using dom4j , when I use chinese character for my chart its shows some other characters,if using english means no problem will occur. kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify proper encoding when reading or writing the file? The safest way to
handle chinese characters is to always provide encoding (eg. utf-8) while reading or
writing the file. Once you have a valid java string, you dont need to worry about encoding
anymore.
Anyway can you post the chinese characters you are dealing with. They might be special ones
that need special handling.

Comment: hi friend, I have tried many ways but still i have the problem in fusion chart. 汽车在记录 i want to set this word as caption in xml. its set properly in xml file. but when I use that character in chart its printing some other characters.

Comment: They are as simple as they get in terms of chinese characters.
So things can go wrong in following places.
1. XML file ( you checked it so it must be fine)
2. File read process (File is not read with proper encoding).
3. View (The viewer has wrong encoding setting, eg web browser has encoding to view Latin instead of UTF-8).
If all 3 can be ruled out, it is Fusion Chart bug.